# How to include class in Angular 4 using conditional statement

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

How can I include class in my router-outlet in index page only. I tried several ways but I couldn't get it work. below is my scripts

```
  <div [ngClass]="{'home' : [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" }">
   <app-navigation></app-navigation>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
```

Thanks for assisting.

Comment: something like this `<h3 [ngClass]="{'large-text': false, 'red-color': true}">Angular 2 Ng Class works with object/map of classes</h3>`

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You want to add class according to the current route ?

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic yes please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like that:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class-route1': r1.isActive, 'class-route2': r2.isActive}">
    <a routerLink="route1" routerLinkActive #r1="routerLinkActive">
        Route1
    </a>
    <a routerLink="route2" routerLinkActive #r2="routerLinkActive">
        Route2
    </a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```